# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after change .dev domain to .test in /etc/hosts for rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosts

I wanted to change development domain to `.test` from `.dev` for our rails app after new Chrome update that forces https for `.dev` domains.

I updated all spots in the app where we were using `.dev` domain. I changed `/etc/hosts` file too. It looks like below. I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error when try access the app in a browser. I see in logs that this request does not hit the app, so it probably fails somewhere earlier. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 example.test
127.0.0.1 www.example.test
127.0.0.1 app.example.test
```

Comment: Solved. I need to add `.test` domain in `/lib/naked_domain_constraint.rb` file. It's app-specific file.

Comment: The HTTPS redirection is not because a Chrome update but because .dev is now a valid top level domain.